# How to disable html button for 24hrs after being clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a html form button that disable after being clicked and will be enable after 24hrs.
The button should work for each users.
How can I fix that?

```
    <p>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='btClickMe' 
            onclick='save(); this.disabled = true;' />
    </p>
    <p id="msg"></p>
<script>
    function save() {
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerHTML = 'Data submitted and the button disabled in 24hrs  &#9786;';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store clicked identifier to cookie which expired after 24 hours from first button clicked (using `document.cookie`)

```html
<input
  type="submit"
  value="Submit"
  id="btClickMe"
/>
<div id="msg">Message Here</div>
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btClickMe");
let get = getCookie("clicked"); // check cookie after page loaded
if (get) {
  btn.disabled = true; // disable the button after page loaded
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function (_event) {
  get = getCookie("clicked"); // check cookie exist
  if (!get) setCookie("clicked", "true", 1); // set cookie after clicked
  btn.disabled = true; // disable the button after button clicked
  var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
  msg.innerHTML = "Data submitted and the button disabled in 24hrs  &#9786;";
});

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == " ") c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}
```

[See Demo](https://codepen.io/dimaslanjaka/pen/bGMLjbK)

Comment: Please, how do I make the button to submit form?

Comment: if you want to force button to enable before cookie exipred, just using this code ( `btn.disabled = false` ), or delete the cookie. check the demo, i updated the demo